# Can a Windows Docker Container access a service on the host machines LAN network?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-container

My problem is that I have a .NetFramework 4.8 server/service that I am trying to containerize in a windows Docker Container and need it to access a service that's connected via network on the local host machine. This server in the container needs to be able to do two things:

1. It needs to connect to a GRPC service that is connected via ethernet on the local host machine. The host machine can access this service via the network using its IP address.
2. The front-end application that runs on the local host machine needs to be able to connect to the containerized server.

I'm able to do #2 by adding mapped ports to the docker-compose when creating the container. However I'm not sure if I'm able to connect to a service that's on the local host machine's network.

Does anyone know if its possible to connect to a network service with docker containers?

When debugging and running the network service locally on the host machine, I tried to access this service from the docker container using `host.docker.internal` but that didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: There are few restrictions on outbound connections from Docker containers. Note that if you're trying to access a service on the host you need to either (a) use the ip address of one of the host's interfaces (possibly via a dns resolved hostname), or (b) use the special name [`host.docker.internal`](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host).